# Unique values in objects

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I have a `URI` object, which I am using for a self-build PHP router. This object contains a `pattern` and `parameters` variable.

- The pattern variable is for holding the actual pattern for the URI, just one string.
- The parameters variable is for holding the type, name and value of the parameters that are contained in one URI. This is an associative array.

The class itself looks like this (basic):

```
class URI
{
    private $pattern;

    private $parameters;

    public function __construct($pattern)
    {
        $this->pattern = $pattern;
    }

    public function getPattern()
    {
        return $this->pattern;
    }

    public function setPattern($pattern)
    {
        $this->pattern = $pattern;
    }

    public function getParameters()
    {
        return $this->parameters;
    }

    public function setParameters($parameters)
    {
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }
}
```

One route on my router, can have multiple URI's in it.

> An example is, the URI "/" and "/home" and "/anotherhome" all redirect
>   to the the same page.

This has multiple of these objects in it. I chose for an object instead of an array so I got more freedom with function design, since I need to still implement the parameters.

When working on troubleshooting when adding the URIs, I wanted to add the following functions:

- You can't add the same URI pattern in the same route, the URI simply gets removed
- The URI pattern can't be the same as another URI on all other route, this would cause conflicts.

When this was just an array, I could do this easily by just using `array_unique` for the first functionality. For the other functionality I also just used standard array functions.

Now I have to collect all the `getPattern()`'s from each object in the URI's array and then check for the same thing.

I'm currently doing this by this method:

```
public function resolveRouteURIs(array $URIs)
{
    $collection = [];
    if (!is_array($URIs)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("The URI's should be in a array");
    }
    foreach ($URIs as $URI) {
        $collection[] = [
            'pattern' => $URI->getPattern(),
            'parameters' => $URI->getParameters()];
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

For re-setting the URI's I'm using this method:

```
//The resolver class
$resolver = new Route\URIs\URI\Resolver(); 

//Some route URIs as object format
$currentRouteURIs = $resolver->resolveRouteURIs($currentRouteURIs);
$URIs = array_unique($currentRouteURIs, SORT_REGULAR);

array_walk($URIs, function (&$URI) {
    $parameters = $URI['parameters'];
    $URI = new Route\URIs\URI\URI($URI['pattern']);
    $URI->setParameters($parameters);

});
```

Is there a better way for doing this?